# SQL Server 2008 how to query comma separated string from one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, xml

Table **POST**:

```
postId  Tag    Author
-----------------------
1       A,B    x,y
2       B,C,D  x
3       C,D    y
```

Questions:

1. How to select records that have Tag='B' in the comma separated string? From the above example it should return record 1,2.
2. How to select records that have Tag='B' and Author='y'? The returned records should be 1.

BTW: if I redesign database scheme into three tables `POST`, `TAG` and `AUTHOR`, then query the desirable records by inner join clause. Compared with the former method, which is better in performance? The table `POST` has 10 thousand records in total.

Comment: If you wnat to search for a list within a list you can not do this on string level! If you want to find an `A` in `A,B,C,D` it's easy, same with `B,C`. But what about `C,B` or `A,C`? Such values **must be stored in separate tables**. In your case I'd suggest a classical `m:n` design with tables for posts, tags and authors and mapping tables between them. Btw: 10.000 records is not much...

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, you know that storing lists as delimited strings is the wrong way to store values in SQL.  Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad designs, but the first step should really be to fix the data model.

To do what you want, you can do:

```
select *
from t
where ',' + tag + ',' like '%,B,%'
```

The second question is similar:

```
where ',' + tag + ',' like '%,B,%' and
      ',' + author + ',' like '%,y,%'
```

Comment: Thanks. The filter value may be 'B,C' other than one single 'B' in production. So, Would be the better choice that these records will be stored in NoSQL database in JSON format ,e.g. LiteDB ?

Comment: The proper way to store a list in SQL is as a table, with one row per list value.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `charindex`?

```
select * from table1 where charindex('B', tag) <> 0;

select * from table1 where charindex('B', tag) <> 0 and charindex('y', author) <> 0;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dac6b/4).

Comment: Thank you for your online demo. The filter value may be 'B,C' other than one single 'B' in production.

Comment: It should still work if you replace `'B'` with `'B,C'`.